# How to check if Facebook Javascript SDK is supported by the browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to check if the Browser supports Facebook Javascript SDK on the browser. Following is the scenario that I am facing with the FB JS SDK.

There are 2 clients one that has access to Facebook and the other that has restricted access to Facebook through Firewall. Since the user with restricted access does not have access to Facebook, none of the callback methods of Facebook work.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The window.fbAsyncInit event is created by the Facebook JavaScript SDK once it is successfully downloaded. If the download fails, the fbAsyncInit event will never fire. You could add some code elsewhere on your page to check whether this event has fired. Additionally, you can check for the global FB JavaScript object. If this object hasn't been initialised, the SDK didn't download.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ for more.

Comment: The SDK is downloaded asynchronously. The getLoginStatus as well is called async. So can I check the FB object before calling the getLoginStatus function and perform the alternatives?

Comment: You can try. The SDK is downloaded async, but once it is downloaded, it'll create and fire the fbAsyncInit event, so you can call the getLoginStatus function from inside that event handler.